# FreeNAS, add os mirror after installation

Tags: zfs, truenas, usb-flash-drive

I have selected two usb sticks to install FreeNAS onto during instllation. Everything is setup now and working.
Can I add a third usb stick as mirror now without reinstalling everything? If so, how?

Also, does the mirrored boot filesystem also receive some resiliency/checksum treatment in FreeNAS?

And if one of the usb drives fails and I stick a new one into the same port, will it rebuild the mirror?